# Different Storyboards for iPad and iPhone not working right

Tags: iphone, ipad, storyboard

I, I have 2 storyboards:

- storyboard_iphone
- storyboard_ipad

I have 4 viewcontrollers, and when I'm using the app in iPads, only 2 view controllers use the storyboard_ipad. The other view controllers take storyboard_iphone.

In my target project info, I have two rows

1. Main storyboard file base name (iPad)= storyboard_ipad
2. Main storyboard file base name = storyboard_iphone

What is the problem?

Comment: can you post the code which you are using for detecting the device and showing the particular storyboard

Comment: I put in Project Info tab. I added one Row ->Main storyboard file base name (iPad)= storyboard_ipad

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below method to get storyboard as per device:

```
-(UIStoryboard*)getStoryBord{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad))
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_ipad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_iphone" bundle:nil];
    }

    return storyboard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to use only one storyboard for all devices. Create universal app and use size classes along with Auto Layout.